# POST http://localhost:3000/serverSide 401 (Unauthorized) Error

Tags: javascript, html, database, postgresql, express

I'm trying to send a username and password from an HTML file to a Javascript file that queries an employee table for that username and password. My problem is that the username and password are set to undefined when they are in my serverSide.js file so a proper query is never taking place. In my console window in chrome I'm getting the error POST http://localhost:3000/serverSide 401 (Unauthorized) Error. Attached below is my code

employee-login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Employee Login - Brookings Activity Center</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <h1>Brookings Activity Center</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="employee-login.html">Employee Login</a>
        <a href="book-event.html">Book an Event</a>
    </nav>

    <section>
        <h2>Employee Login</h2>
        <form id="loginForm" action = "/serverSide" method = "POST">
            <input id = "username" type="text" placeholder="Username" required>
            <br>
            <input id = "password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <br>
            <button type="button" id = "loginButton">Login</button>
        </form>
        <!-- Not implemented, prototype.-->
        <a href="#forgot-password.html">Forgot password?</a>
    </section>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('loginButton').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission (default behavior)
            
            // Username and password being passed
            const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
            const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    
            // Send login request to server
            fetch('http://localhost:3000/serverSide', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    // Username and password match, redirect to employee homepage
                   // window.location.href = 'employeeHomepage.html';
                   alert('Username or Password matches');
                } else {
                    // Username or password is incorrect, display error message
                    alert('Username or Password is incorrect');
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                alert('An error occurred. Please try again later.');
            });
        });
    </script>

    <footer>
        &copy; Brookings Activity Center
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

serverSide.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { Client } = require('pg');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Enable CORS for all routes
 app.use(cors());

// Middleware to parse request body
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Database connection configuration
const dbConfig = {
  user: 'postgres',
  password: '1234',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  database: 'BAC_DB',
};

// Create a new PostgreSQL client
const client = new Client(dbConfig);

// Connect to the database
client.connect()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to PostgreSQL database');

    // Define route for employee login
    app.post('/serverSide', (req, res) => {
      const { username, password } = req.body;
      console.log('Received username:', username);
      console.log('Received password:', password);

      // Check the database for the provided username and password
      client.query('SELECT * FROM employee WHERE username = $1 AND password = $2', [username, password], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error executing query', err);
          res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
        } else {
          if (result.rows.length > 0) {
            // Username and password match, send success response
            res.status(200).json({ success: true });
           // res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'Username or Password is incorrect -- server side' });
          } else {
            // Username or password is incorrect, send error response
            res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'Username or Password is incorrect -- server side' });
            // res.status(200).json({ success: true });
          }
        }
      }); 
         // For now, let's just send a response back to the client
        // res.send('Received login request');
    }); 

    // Start the server
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error connecting to PostgreSQL database', err);
  });
```

I tried debugging by checking what the username and password is when being sent to serverSide.js by using console.log. Both the username and password show up as undefined so for some reason the username and password are not being sent over properly.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

With

```
app.use(express.json());
```

On your serverSide

Comment: app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

Using both not only for one.